# How to access credentials from vault using roleID & secretID through spring b?

Tags: spring-boot, credentials, vault

I’m trying to access the credentials kept at a vault location through spring boot, I have roleID , secretID, nameSpace, vaultPath & address given to me.
The credentials are kept at a specific vault path.
I am trying to configure this in application.yml, but it fails, also trying to figure out where to specify the vault path.

```
application.yml:
  spring:
    application:
      name: DIT

spring.cloud.vault:
  authentication: APPROLE
  scheme: https
  uri: <uri>
  namespace:
  app-role:
  role-id:
  secret-id:
```